# Restrict downloading of documents from sharepoint with edit permissions

Tags: permissions, excel, download

Can I restrict users from downloading documents if they have edit permissions in sharepoint?
I have an excel file that my staff all need to collaborate on, but I do not want anyone to be able to download it. Is this possible?

Comment: so, did any of these answers provide an answer to your question?

Answer (score 1):

If they are editors there is no way of blocking that. You can look into Information Rights Management (IRM) to further control what they can do with the document (like block printing).

Comment: That's true - if they need to Edit, then they will be able to Download files.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [MS link on Permissions Levels](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/sites/user-permissions-and-permission-levels) - note that a 'Permission Level' is comprised of lots of individual 'Permissions'.  All the individual Permissions, when group together = the Permission Level.  (Hopefully I'm not confusing you with the explanation.

It seems like `View Only` or `Restricted Read` would satisfy your requirements.  But to test it prior to putting actual users in the groups and going live.

**EDIT (following Marek's post):** it would not be possible to restrict users from downloading documents, since you want them to have Edit permissions - in order to edit documents, users need to be able to download them.

The `View Only` and `Read` Permissions Levels are standard 'Out of the Box' Permissions.  If you check your existing Sharepoint user groups, you will see these Permission Levels being used.

(CAUTION: do not modify the standard 'Out of the Box' Permissions Levels - although it is possible to make a custom, new Permission Level).

Below is a screen-shot from my own explanation file on Permissions.  (`Restricted Read` is only available on Publishing Sites).

[image: Permissions]

[image: Permissions2]